# Query to select samples from A and B

Tags: sql, sql-server, databricks

I have two populations A and B. I need to first select 10 unique random samples from A. Then I need to select 10 unique random samples from B, which are not in the samples selected from A either. The uniqueness is based on ID only. while there are 10 unique IDs, the total rows can be more.

I followed these steps. First I got 10 distinct sample from A which I used to get corresponding rows.
1.

```
select * from A t1 inner join (select distinct id from A
tablesample(10 rows)) t2 where t1.id = t2.id Stored this as A_records
```

2. I created a temporary view to store the pool available for B. This removes any IDs of the first sample from reappearing in B (while its not needed, I did it for my own sanity)

```
create or replace view B_pool as (select distinct id from B where B.Id
not in (select distinct ID from A_records)
```

3. Now I selected sample from B

```
select * from B t1 inner join (select distinct ID from B_pool
tablesample(10 rows)) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

I feel like this logic should work. But, I still seem to get duplicates in the overall samples(samples from B contain the IDs that are in the samples from A).

How can I avoid getting these duplicates?

Some sample data for the population A and B and the desired results for A and B

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f81ln.png)

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY8g4.png)

Comment: You need to show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Side notes: 1. Calling a column ID when it is not the table's unique ID is a bad idea. It got me confused for a moment. 2. In the [databricks docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-sampling.html) they say that `TABLESAMPLE(x ROWS)` doesn't get you random rows, but just the first rows it happens to read (or so I understand this). You may be fine with this or not.

Comment: The queries look fine to me. They both produce rows with distinct IDs not contained in the other set.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

The queries look fine to me. They both produce rows with IDs not contained in the other set.

A simple way to access different IDs is by using the modulo function. E.g. use `where mod(id,2) = 0` for one data set and `where mod(id,2) = 1` for the other. You can divide by any number of course to make this look more random than even IDs in one set and odd IDs in the other, as long as there are enough rows in the table, e.g.: `where mod(id,123) = 45`.

Full queries:

```
select *
from A 
where id in (select distinct id 
             from A
             where mod(id,2) = 0 
             limit 10);

select * 
from B
where id in (select distinct id 
             from B
             where mod(id,2) = 1 
             limit 10);
```

You can add some `ORDER BY` clause to the subqueries if you need randomness.

Comment: Side note: I just see that databricks also supports the modulo operator `%`. So you can write `id % 2 = 0 ` instead of `mod(id,2) = 0 `, if you like that better.

Comment: Thank you. your answer does work for this scenario considering I have shown only two populations. In the actual practice, I have few more populations and need to ensure any of the IDs from the previous arent used in the following populations. 

I did check out the way databricks implements the tablesample. But, since I did a distinct of the ID and performed a tablesample on it, I thought it could work. databricks suggests to use percentage if true randomness is desired. I think I can use the percent calculation by using (10*100/totalrecords) value and ensure randomness into it.

Comment: Well, as mentioned, you can use the modulo approach with any divisor. `id % 4 = 0`, `id % 4 = 1`, `id % 4 = 2`, `id % 4 = 3` for four populations for instance. Or `id % 23 = 5`, `id % 23 = 11`, `id % 23 = 13`, `id % 23 = 19` for four populations with IDs that don't so easily let see the access pattern :-) Whatever you like.

Comment: Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/SsUtJH20. There are thousand IDs in each of my sample tables. Divided by 23, I get approximately 43 rows per query with my modulo approach, which is enough to pick the final 10. And there is room for 19 more population samples with the divisor 23.

Comment: And here is a demo with random IDs. The queries will look slightly different in databricks, but you see that the selected IDs are really random while it it still guaranteed to have no overlappings, because of the modulo access. https://dbfiddle.uk/oBeCDQ42